# Bash - add a date

Tags: bash

I am using bash. Could someone tell me why is this:

```
mv file.txt file.txt_$(date +%F-%T)
```

...working as expected, giving me `file_2017-01-05-13:46:50`

while renaming multiple files with `rename`:

```
rename 's/file/file_$(date +%F-%T)/' *.txt
```

.. is not working as expected, giving me `file_1000 4 24 27 30 46 118 127 1000date +%F-%T).txt` and I want multiple renamed files with a date and time?

Comment: Use double quotes.. `rename "s/file/file_$(date +%F-%T)/" *.txt`

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me how to rename all the files in a directory, not just those having 'file' word in it?

Comment: so you want to add date after filename in all the files, right?

Comment: If so then try this `rename "s/(.*)/\1_$(date +%F-%T)/" *.txt`